# Best way to hold sets of related elements dynamically added

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of files, and the filenames for those files contain some characters then an underscore, then anything else like so:

`test_123.txt`

What I'm trying to do is loop through these files, pull out the 'prefix' (the characters up to but not including the `_`, add the prefix to a list if it's not already in the list, and then add the whole filename as an element of that prefix.

That might be confusing so here's an example:

List of file names:

```
A_ieie.txt
B_ldld.txt
C_test.txt
A_232.txt
B_file2.txt
C_345.txt
```

So I am looping through these files and get the prefix like so:

```
string prefix = fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf('_'));
```

Now, I check if that prefix is already in a list of prefixes, and if not, add it:

```
List<string> prefixes = new List<string>();

if (!prefixes.Contains(prefix))
{
    prefixes.Add(prefix);
}
```

So here's the prefixes that would be added to that list:

```
A //not yet seen, add it to list
B //not yet seen, add it to list
C //not yet seen, add it to list
A //already seen, don't add
B //already seen, don't add
C //already seen, don't add
```

Okay the above is easy to do, but what about when I want to add the filenames that share a prefix to a list?

Since these are going to be dynamically added and could be anything, I can't make several lists before hand. I thought about have a `List` of `lists`, but is that really the best way to do this? Would a class be ideal?

The end goal of the above example would be something like :

```
[0][0] = A_ieie.txt   //This is the 'A' list
[0][1] = A_232.txt  
[1][0] = B_ldld.txt   //This is the 'B' list
[1][1] = B_file2.txt  
[2][0] = C_test.txt   //This is the 'C' list
[2][1] = C_345.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want a Dictionary:

```
var list = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
```

The `Key` would be the "prefix" and the `Value` would be a list of strings (the filenames).

**EDIT**

If you want the list of filenames to be unique, perhaps a HashSet is a better option:

```
var list = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<string>>();
```

Comment: Hmm that sounds like a good idea. Forgot about dictionaries. I'll test it out and let you know how it works. Thank you!

Comment: @Lee Gunn and if he doesn't want the file names to be repeated, is Dictionary<string, List<ISet>>() correct?

Comment: Yeah, true, if that's an issue then perhaps a HashSet instead of a List<string>

Comment: Agreed! +1 on that

Comment: All the answers work, but you were first. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a Dictionary>

Then, each list is referenced by a key integer (or use a string to "name" the list):

```
public Dictionary<string, List<string>> myBookList = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    private void addList(string listName, List<string> contents)
    {
        myBookList.Add(listName, contents);
        //direct add
        List<string> science_Fiction_Books = new List<string>();

        myBookList.Add("Science Fiction", science_Fiction_Books);
        myBookList["Science_Fiction"].Add("mytitle.txt");
        myBookList["Science_Fiction"][0] = "My book title.txt";
        string fileLocation = @"c:\mydirectory\mylists\myBookTitle.txt";
        myBookList["Science_Fiction"].Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileLocation));
        //etc.
    }
```

Comment: YOu can also do a Dictionary<bool,List<string>> using alreadySeen as a key

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
var textFileNameList =
  new List<string>{"A_ieie.txt","B_ldld.txt","C_test.txt",
                    "A_232.txt","B_file2.txt","C_345.txt"};

        var groupedList = textFileNameList.GroupBy(t => t.Split('_')[0])
            .Select( t=> new {

                Prefix = t.Key,
                Files = t.Select( file=> file).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `linq` to achieve this.

```
List<string> List = new List<string>() { "A_ieie.txt", "B_ldld.txt",    "C_test.txt", "A_232.txt", "B_file2.txt", "C_345.txt" };
Dictionary<string, List<string>> Dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
Dict = List.GroupBy(x => x.Split('_')[0]).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```